# Why I get a 1282 error after glLoadIdentity() is invoked?

Tags: c, opengl, 3d, glsl, opengl-compat

**CODE:**

```
 int err = glGetError();  // err = 0

 glMatrixMode(GL_TEXTURE);
 err = glGetError();      // err = 0

 glLoadIdentity();
 err = glGetError();      // err = 1282
```

**GL_INVALID_OPERATION**
The specified operation is not allowed in the current state. The offending command is ignored and has no other side effect than to set the error flag.

I use gDEBugger to check openGL's state when I get the error.

```
GL_CURRENT_RASTER_POSITION_VALID=TRUE
GL_CURRENT_RASTER_TEXTURE_COORDS=N/A
GL_CURRENT_TEXTURE_COORDS=N/A
GL_PROJECTION_STACK_DEPTH=1
GL_TEXTURE_1D=FALSE
GL_TEXTURE_2D=FALSE
GL_TEXTURE_GEN_Q=N/A
GL_TEXTURE_GEN_R=N/A
GL_TEXTURE_GEN_S=N/A
GL_TEXTURE_GEN_T=N/A
GL_TEXTURE_MATRIX=N/A
GL_TEXTURE_STACK_DEPTH=N/A
GL_TEXTURE_BINDING_1D=0
GL_TEXTURE_BINDING_2D=0
GL_TEXTURE_BINDING_3D=0
GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE=GL_MODULATE
GL_TEXTURE_ENV_COLOR={0, 0, 0, 0}
GL_ACTIVE_TEXTURE=GL_TEXTURE11
GL_CLIENT_ACTIVE_TEXTURE=GL_TEXTURE0
GL_MAX_TEXTURE_UNITS=4
GL_ACTIVE_TEXTURE_ARB=GL_TEXTURE11
GL_CLIENT_ACTIVE_TEXTURE_ARB=GL_TEXTURE0
GL_MAX_TEXTURE_UNITS_ARB=4
```

I can not figure out where is wrong. Why not the simply operation can not be allowed?

Comment: You shouldn't even be using `glMatrixMode()` and `glLoadIdentity()` anymore, they are deprecated.

Comment: @Vallentin I know, but I must consider the compatibility of old opengl version.

Comment: You can still create and use your own Matrix Stack within the old versions of OpenGL.

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation:

> GL_INVALID_OPERATION is generated if glLoadIdentity is executed
>   between the execution of glBegin and the corresponding execution of
>   glEnd.

I guess that it is why.

Comment: I don't think that is the reason of my problem. but when I invoke glActiveTexture() before I use glMatrixMode(GL_TEXTURE), the error is gone. I don't know why.

Answer (score -1):

Immediate mode, along with matrix handling on the OpenGL side, is deprecated. You should be getting the same error even if you use glMatrixMode. Switching to OpenGL version 2.1 with wglCreateContextAttribsARB worked for me, although I've read comments saying it's not guaranteed that it will work in the future. You have to do your own matrix calculus and VBOs right from the start now.